# function vs class vs module vs package vs session for fixture scopes in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, pytest-fixtures

I set 5 fixtures with `function`, `class`, `module`, `package` and `session` scopes to `test1()` as shown below:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def fixture_function():
    print('function')

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def fixture_class():
    print('class')

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def fixture_module():
    print('module')

@pytest.fixture(scope='package')
def fixture_package():
    print('package')

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def fixture_session():
    print('session')

class Test1:
    def test1(
        self,
        fixture_function,
        fixture_class,
        fixture_module,
        fixture_package,
        fixture_session
    ):
        pass
```

Then, I ran the command below:

```
pytest -q -rP
```

Then, each fixture ran once according to the result below:

```
$ pytest -q -rP
.                               [100%]
=============== PASSES =============== 
____________ Test1.test1 _____________
_______ Captured stdout setup ________
session
package
module
class
function
1 passed in 0.10s
```

My questions:

1. What is the difference between `function`, `class`, `module`, `package` and `session` for fixture scopes in Pytest?
2. When should I use fixture scopes in Pytest?

Comment: [Check this page from documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/fixtures.html)

Answer (score 1):

The fixture's state is stored within the designated "scope".
The term `scope` refers to the parameter that determines when the fixture will be invoked. If the `scope` is set to `function`, the fixture will be invoked separately for each test as a function. Alternatively, if the `scope` is set to `module`, the fixture will only be invoked once for the entire current module.

For costly requests giving the same results, this feature optimizes the test duration.

> Fixtures requiring network access depend on connectivity and are
> usually time-expensive to create. Extending the previous example, we
> can add a scope="module" parameter to the @pytest.fixture invocation
> to cause a smtp_connection fixture function, responsible to create a
> connection to a preexisting SMTP server, to only be invoked once per
> test module (the default is to invoke once per test function).
> Multiple test functions in a test module will thus each receive the
> same smtp_connection fixture instance, thus saving time. Possible
> values for scope are: function, class, module, package or session.

Source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html